# Can't change weights in neural network

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm doing simple code

```
net = network(2,3,[1; 0; 0],[1 1;0 0;0 0],...
    [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 1 0],[0 0 1]);

net.inputs{1}.size = 1;
net.inputs{2}.size = 1;

P = [0 0; 0 0; 1 1]
A = sim(net, P.');

net.inputs{1}.range = [0 1];
net.inputs{2}.range = [0 1];
net.b{1} = 1/4
net.IW{1, 1} = [0.5]
net.IW{1, 2} = [0.5]
net.IW{2, 1} = [0.5]
net.IW{3, 2} = [0.5]
gensim(net)
```

everything seems fine until I try to change net.b{1} and weights.
I get always the same error:

```
??? Error using ==> network.subsasgn>network_subsasgn at 535
```

net.b{1} must be a 0-by-1 matrix.

I tried doing it with and without brackets
net.b{1} = 1/4
net.b{1} = [1/4]
but I get the same error. I just don't understand what am I doing wrong, documentation doesn't help at all, I've read it for this parameters several times (maybe I'm just stupid)